# Sonar scanner bug results does not appear on sonarqube dashboard

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I was installed Sonarqube server on my machine and I am running sonarscanner for msbuild described in [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild)

These are the commands:

```
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"org.sonarqube:sonarqube-scanner-msbuild" /n:"Project Name" /v:"1.0"
MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
```

All steps succeeded and showing results on command prompt but the analysis results doesn't appear on dashboard.
What's the problem?

[image: sonarqube dashboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved so that my .Net project name was 'TestProject'.
Because of it contains 'Test' keyword, sonar automatically detect it as a test project and doesn't transport bugs and issues to the dashboard.